# The best way to create a popup box login with php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I need some help with something. I will be creating a popup login with Jquery with php code.

And my question is what is the best way to go.

1. Must php and jquery communicate with each other or can I keep them separate ?
2. I want to write Popup with Jquery and login code with php. I want my code as clean as it can go so there will not be any problems in the future.

I don't need any code for it, I will create it my self. I just need your opinion.

Sorry for my English.It is not that good. I hope my question is clear so you can understand it.

Comment: if php and jquery doesn't communicate you will loose the interactiveness of your website.

Comment: http://blog.theonlytutorials.com/a-very-simple-jquery-popup-ready-to-use-code/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to verify the login credentials within the popup, you need some sort of communication between jquery and PHP. -> AJAX.

PHP -> Serverside
Jquery -> Clientside

So offcourse you will have to use 2 different languages and be a clean programmer, i don't understand your number 2 question.

Comment: I want to write the validation code and mysql code in php and popup code with jquery

Comment: That's the only way to do it, so what is your question?

Comment: then my questien is answer thanks for all answer